# Is there a way to switch from `autocomplete` to `renderAsEmbeddedForm` in EasyAdmin4 when an entity doesn't exist?

Tags: php, symfony, easyadmin

I have the a doctrine entity `Reservation` which has a ManyToOne relation with `Customer`, In easyadmin I made some crud controllers and everything works fine.
The thing is in the `Reservation` creation form I can use:

- `AssociationField::new('customer')->autocomplete()` or
- `AssociationField::new('customer')->renderAsEmbeddedForm()`;

What i would like is to have the autocomplete field and being able to maybe pop up the renderAsEmbeddedForm if the given customer is not found.

**Imagine this:**
Scenario 1:
I am a restaurant owner taking a call for a reservation, the customer tells me his name, i search it in the autocomplete field, find him and we all are happy.
Scenario 2: I am a restaurant owner taking a call for a reservation, the customer tells me his name, i search it in the autocomplete field, I can't find him and I can push a button to make a pop up form (like renderAsEmbeddedForm) come up to enter the customer information.

I already tried using Symfony UX Autocomplete and using a custom twig template and form but i would prefer to stay in the easyadmin crud controller